# I cannot see false value but whole url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i have boolean value "approved". Once I add this as a parameter after link_to it shows me whole url instead of false value. True value works fine. Do you have please any idea where can be issue?

[image]
[image]

```
<tr>
    <td><%= adminpage.email %></td>
    <td><%= adminpage.first_name %></td>
    <td><%= adminpage.last_name %></td>
    <td><%= adminpage.level %></td>
    <td><%= adminpage.approved %>
    <td><%= link_to adminpage.approved, approve_user_url(adminpage.id), method: :put %></td>
    <td><%= if adminpage.approved then "Approved" else "Waiting for approval" end %></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Can we see the code? Maybe the one of that view

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or copied and edited to create a solution.**

Comment: just attached the screenshot .. cannot figure out how to add on the main page without link ...

Comment: You normally see the ternary operator used in place of `if ... then`, so `if x then y else z end` becomes `x ? y : z`.

Comment: From the [docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to): _"If `nil` is passed as the name the value of the link itself will become the name."_ – apparently `false` is treated like `nil`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`link_to` has a first argument that must be *truthful* or it just shows the raw URL. The `false` isn't cutting it. Consider:

```
link_to admin_page.approved.to_s, ...
```

I tend to interpret it like this:

```
link_to admin_page.approved ? 'Yes' : 'No', ...
```

In this particular case it's like you want the whole link to be conditional, more like this:

```
<%- if admin_page.approved -%>
  <%= link_to 'Yes', ... %>
<%- else -%>
  No
<%- end -%>
```